# Percentage of an inline video watched

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I'm developing a website using PHP. On the site I would like to display an inline video for the user to view. Once he's happy he's viewed enough he will then click a link to another page. On this page I wish to display how much of the video he watched.

Is this possible?

I assume I'll require some javascript or similar since the video will be playing on the client side?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how the video is being viewed

Comment: Is this video rendered in HTML5 or Flash?

Comment: I've not yet put the page together. What would be the best way to display the video? HTML 5 may be an issue here in South Africa since a lot of people don't run up to date browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://flv-player.net/ works very well, open source and customisable.

Of particular interest to you may be: http://flv-player.net/players/js/

You will be able to use the values of 'position' and 'duration' to work it out as it's played.

Answer (score 0):

If you use flowplayer you can use player.getTime() to determine the amount of the video played, and `player.getClip().fullDuration` to get the full length of the video, so the percentage played is simply `player.getTime()`/`player.getClip().fullDuration`

http://flowplayer.org/

Comment: Looks like a good solution but I'd like something free of branding